# Effectiveness of Shorinji Kempo and acupuncture pressure point attacks

Tags: technique, self-defense

Please refer to the following [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AZiJ8nAkIsI).
Do these techniques work well when defending in a street fight or in pressure point/acupunture attacks?

How can someone learn what is the way to attack each point (for instance slapping or hitting)? Is there a internet source that this subject can be learnt thoroughly? How can someone practice this solo (with no partners)?

Comment: I've edited your question a bit to make your question more clear. If you disagree with my changes feel free to roll them back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I practice this style. Don't even try to learn this without an instructor. In the unlikely event you find the points you will likely do yourself serious damage.

They do work on most people and those shown are not even the most effective/dangerous. Learning the points is not difficult with the right recourses but some require specific angles to work, others must be struck and others are deep inside the neck. You have to push your finger into the neck to reach them.

Also in a real fight these are useful but not at all sufficient. No one will stand still and let you poke them. You need a system of techniques that set up the opertunities to use these. And lots of sparring practice.

If you want to take something from Shorinji Kempo that is useful, learn the meiuchi. Its a strike with the fingers in a whip like action to the eyes or groin. Easy to learn easy to incorperate into other styles and very effective.

Comment: Thanks a lot Huw Evans, Can you please add sources (may be video) to the meiuchi and to source of the effective pressure points?

Comment: I'll find a meiuchi video. You wont find any clinical trials on these points though. It would never pass a research ethics committee. The points are nothing magic but I cant link to research.

Comment: So to say ... 'yeah it works' - as long you use the special technique ... on pressure points like groin and eyes. So yeah I agree eyes gouching and a kick to the balls always work.

Comment: Lets put it this way: I can make it work using other points. I just don't advise poking yourself in the neck to try to find a point that can knock you out.

Answer (score 1):

I don´t think that you can use that on the street, I mean you can try, but there is a good chance that you don´t hit the right spot as in a real fight everything is happening much faster and your opponent will surely not be just standing and waiting for you to attack the right  place.

**I personally** doubt that those techniques work for defense anyway, for massage or rehab purposes pressure points would may have some value.

Comment: This is exactly why you train for endless numbers of hours - so that you can hit spots when you need to, and you've already encountered most complications by the time you need to use the techniques for real.

Comment: The only possibility I see them work, would be in close range like clinching or on the ground. Wherever there is space for punches, I dont think your opponent will let you 'touch' those pressure points or maybe for releasing a specific hold ex full nelson or similar. I would like to see the proof of it that it works in a real fight! A Video would be of great value.

Comment: You can leverage some spots while clinching, but the better time to hit them is while closing or grappling. You are right that nobody is going to let you walk up and hit a spot, but that's why you train in combinations and kata - you may need several moves to set up for the final one. In the linked video in the question the last demo was the most accurate, a kick is used to position the opponent before moving and finishing them.